# Associação de categorias em PHP e MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um site que tem itens, um item pode ter mais de uma categoria, como faço a linkagem dessas categorias com esse unico produto?

Comment: Vai precisar de 3 tabelas, uma para itens, outra para categorias e a terceira vai ter os campos id do item e id da categoria, depois é só fazer uns inner joins para pegar toda a informação.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você deve fazer um relacionamento de 1 para N, você deve utilizar isso quando uma tabela precisa se relacionar com vários registros de outra tabela.

Você vai ter a tabela item e a tabela categoria e mais uma tabela que você pode chamar de categoria_item. Nela você vai relacionar as outras duas tabelas.

Exemplo da tabela categoria_item:

```
categoria_item
- id_item
- id_categoria
```

Comment: entendi, mas como vou aplicar isso no PHP, na verdade estou iniciando e gostaria de saber também como pego do banco as categorias e coloco em formas de checkbox, assim quando eu selecionar as categorias a que o item pertence, já enviar para o banco as alterações.

Comment: Isso é simples amigo, quando você for salvar o item você vai mandar todas as categorias que o cara selecionou e com isso você vai fazer um loop e cada iteração do loop você vai salvar os dados na tabela categoria_item.

Answer (score -2):

> Pelo que pude entender, você quer fazer uma consulta entre as tabelas
>   relacionadas correto!? Seguindo esse raciocínio você pode tentar o
>   seguinte:

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Cria uma conexão
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Verifica a conexão
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Erro de conexão: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


// Monta o comando SQL para fazer a consulta
$sql = "SELECT i.nome, i.preco, c.nome as nomecategoria FROM item i INNER JOIN categoria c ON c.id = i.id_categoria";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // Saída dos dados a cada registro
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Item nome: " . $row["nome"]. " - preço: " . $row["preco"]. " - Categoria: " . $row["nomecategoria"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Sem resultados.";
}

// Encerra a conexão
$conn->close();
?>
```

> Espero ter ajudado!
>   
>   Referência: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp